# PyDev eclipse is not showing compilation errors

Tags: python, eclipse, compilation, eclipse-plugin, pydev

PyDev is not giving me errors for anything but indentation errors. Any idea what to do here? I'm missing something.
It is not showing autocompletes as well.

I'm using Eclipse Mars. Version: Mars.1 Release (4.5.1)

Please help.

Comment: what version of `pydev` are you running

Answer (score 7):

With the information provided, it sounds like your Python file is not being fully analysed by PyDev because it is not in a Python Source Folder in a PyDev project.

Things to check:

- Is the python file in a [PyDev project](http://www.pydev.org/manual_101_project_conf.html)?
- Is the python file in a [Python Source Folder](http://www.pydev.org/manual_101_project_conf2.html)?

Comment: missing Python source folder was my problem, note I had to restart eclipse before the errors showed up in the editor